# What to do if I mark the wrong flag?

Tags: support, flagging

I accidently marked the wrong flag for a [clash of clans](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174266/i-cant-transfer-my-coc-account-from-android-to-an-ipad-mini) question. I truly have no idea what it flagged, but I meant to put it as a low-quality question.

If I flag a question with the wrong flag, what should I do or say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for notifying us the best.

Thanks for the flag and the note - all is good and the flag was handled already.