# What should we do if we misflag a post?

Tags: support, flagging

It was a case of the tap-too-quick, and I selected the wrong flag for a particular question. How should I handle this matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't see any flags by you which seemed odd/wrong, so it probably got handled already. Also, there isn't a big difference between the flag types as far as moderator notification is concerned: we get notified, look at flag *and* post and try to resolve whatever problem the post may have (at least that's the idea, we all make mistakes now and then).

The answer in [What to do if I mark the wrong flag?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/what-to-do-if-i-mark-the-wrong-flag?rq=1) still applies though: If in doubt, post to Meta (as you did).